# PostGIS Error: type "geography" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I just upgraded my development machine to Windows 7 and am therefore reinstalling PostgreSQL and PostGIS.  I used the [Postgres Plus installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/postgres-plus/download), as recommended on the Postgres website, and followed [this tutorial](http://get.enterprisedb.com/docs/Tutorial_All_PPSS_PostGIS.pdf) for installation.  I created a database using the template_postgis and the application that I am currently developing was able to connect to the database with no problems.

However, my old code is not able to create tables using the PostGIS `Geography` like it used to.  For example, when I try to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_area (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(1000),
    area GEOGRAPHY(POLYGON, 4326),
    start_time DATE,
    end_time DATE
)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  type "geography" does not exist
LINE 4:         area GEOGRAPHY(POLYGON, 4326),
                     ^
```

If I look under the database in the Object brower of pgAdmin III, I see a bunch of `Geometry` functions, so the installation seems to have run correctly.  I'm not sure what my problem might be.  Is it possible for the installer to only install PostGIS `Geometry`, but not `Geography`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got my question answered over on the [GIS site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13305/postgis-error-type-geography-does-not-exist/13311#13311).  I had PostGIS 1.4 installed, but `Geography` was not added until PostGIS 1.5.  So I had to uninstall what I had and re-install Postgres.  I had great difficulty finding a version that included PostGIS 1.5, though.  I was given the advice to not use the "Postgres Plus" proprietary software, though, since it takes EnterpriseDB time to port the most up-to-date add-ons and such.  Instead I was redirected to the regular PostgreSQL download on the EnterpriseDB website, which is surprisingly tricky to find.  [Here it is](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows).  The 64-bit version did not come with PostGIS, so I had to use the 32-bit version instead, which worked.  Finally!

Answer (score 72):

I have experienced this issue before as well, but what helped me was not the answer on the GIS site.

I have Postgresql installed via Homebrew and I also have the Postgresql app installed. As for PostGIS, however, I installed it via Homebrew.

When I encountered this problem, I was running the Postgresql app instead of running it in Terminal, so of course you'd get this PostGIS error because PostGIS was never installed on the Postgresql app. Once I started Postgresql in Terminal, it worked for me.

**Update 9/25/2014:**

It's possible that you did not create the extension for PostGIS in your database:

```
$ psql

psql> \c databaseName;

psql> CREATE EXTENSION Postgis;
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe  ther are some problems with the  postgis, first see if the type "geography" is exist? 
just as the follwing;

db_lbs=> \dT geography

```
        List of data types
 Schema |   Name    | Description 
--------+-----------+-------------
 lbs    | geography | 
(1 row)
```

By the way, please take attention to the current search_path;

I guess the type "geography" is not exist in your schema, may it  exists in public schema, 
So check it first。

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue, I resolved it by un-installing postgres, postgis and reinstalled followed by the official installation documentation.
For windows:

http://postgis.net/windows_downloads

For Ubuntu & OSX:

http://postgis.net/install

Answer (score 1):

If somebody experience the same error while connecting to the Heroku application, written using Qurkus, the fix is the following -- there is need to appedn `?currentSchema=YOUR_CURRENT_SCHEMA` to the JDBC URI